# Getting the Image Title (not the post title)

Tags: title

I've tried over a dozen variations of getting the title now, with mixed results. I get an error, blank output, or the *post* title, but not the *image* title.

For reference, here's the complete image code (with my latest attempt) I'm using in posts:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<a href="<?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full', false ); echo esc_url( $src[0] ); ?>" title="<?php the_title( $attachment_id ); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'itemprop' => 'image' ) ); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The specific bit I'm having difficulty with:

`<?php the_title( $attachment_id ); ?>`

Comment: If by "title" you meant the image's caption, then the default one is stored in a post meta named `_wp_attachment_image_alt`. But an image can have various captions and not necessarily be stored in the database, and can be set by a plugin or the active theme, so you may need to use a plugin/theme -specific function to get the title in question.

Comment: No, I'm not referring to the alt, caption, description, filename, or URL; I mean the title. When you're on the attachment page itself, it's not a problem. `<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>` will suffice just fine. However, when you're viewing the image on a page or post, it adopts their title. I never noticed the problem before (until someone else mentioned it), but I cannot figure out how to override this behavior.

Comment: My apologies, by "caption", I was actually referring to the image's *alt text*..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The specific bit I'm having difficulty with:
>
> ```
> <?php the_title( $attachment_id ); ?>
> ```

- [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) doesn't have a post ID parameter, and the first parameter is actually a text/markup to prepend to the title. And note that attachments like images in the WordPress media library have their own posts, where the type (i.e. `post_type`) is `attachment`.
- `the_title()` uses the global `$post` variable which references the current post in the main (WordPress) query. (therefore the function doesn't need a post ID as a parameter)
- [`the_title_attribute()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title_attribute/) also by default uses the same `$post` global mentioned above, so that explains the "*when you're viewing the image on a page or post, it adopts their title*" in your comment.
- Both the above functions use [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) to get the post title, hence you could use that function to get the title of an image (or any other attachment in the media library) by the image/attachment ID.

  I.e. Use `echo get_the_title( $attachment_id )` instead of `the_title( $attachment_id )`.

However, for use in an HTML attribute like the `title` attribute, you would want to use [`the_title_attribute()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title_attribute/) which sanitizes/escapes the title and works with *any posts* (regular Posts, Pages, attachments, etc.), but to make the function works for a *specific post only*, use the `post` argument and pass a post *object*, like so, which uses [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) to get the post object:

```
<a href="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>"
    title="<?php the_title_attribute( array( 'post' => get_post( $attachment_id ) ) );
?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'itemprop' => 'image' ) ); ?></a>
```

<sub>But actually looking at the source, passing a post ID, i.e. `the_title_attribute( array( 'post' => $attachment_id ) )`, *should* also work because the value is only used with `get_the_title()` which accepts either a post ID or object.</sub>

And note that I intentionally used [`the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_url/) in the above code.. because that's a simpler way to display/echo the post thumbnail's URL, for any image sizes like `full`, `thumbnail`, `custom`, etc. :)

Comment: Here's what finally worked: `<?php $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ); the_title_attribute( array( 'post' => get_post( $attachment_id ) ) ); ?>`. The array was the key. Do you think there's a better/cleaner/simpler way to accomplish outputting an image title, or is this the best it gets within the context of manually writing out the parts of an attachment like this?

Comment: WordPress core does have a function for displaying a post thumbnail's *caption* (which is the *post excerpt*), namely [`the_post_thumbnail_caption()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_caption/), which uses `wp_get_attachment_caption()`. But as for the *post thumbnail's or an attachment's **title*** (`post_title`), there are no such functions, but you can make your own and just call it from within your template, e.g. `my_the_post_thumbnail_title()`. PS: Sorry for the late reply , and secondly, I reworded my answer and hopefully it helps you more. :)